# Abaqus Monitoring Progress on Terminal

Tags: abaqus

I have many analysises to do which will take more than 4-5 hours for each one so I want to monitor the number of increments on the terminal. I'll use noGui method,btw. Is there anyway to do it via python script.

Answer (score 1):

While a Python script or a Fortran subroutine could be used to monitor an analysis, they are not necessary. Instead, there is a simple method to view the status of the job as it runs that does not require opening the CAE:

**Open the *'status'*, the *'data'*, or the *'message'* file**. Among other things, Abaqus automatically creates a `.dat` file, a `.sta` file, and a `.msg` file for every analysis job that is run. For example: `Job-1.sta`. These files are typically placed in the current work directory. The `.sta` file is the most concise of these, and provides information regarding steps, increments, iterations, etc.

Note: these are just text files and can be opened in any text editor, even as the analysis runs, and the current state of the analysis when the file is opened can be reviewed. In fact, from the command line you could use tools such as `more` (Windows) or `less` (Linux).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I coded a script to read .sta file and created my own progress bar.

Comment: Nice! I've used the (Fortran) subroutine UEXTERNALDB to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I’m working on a free web app which diagnoses convergence problems found in the msg file. It also makes plots which show the progress of the analysis.
https://msgfile.info

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Linux environment and all your different jobs are run in the same directory, use:
    `tail -f *.sta`
If your jobs are run at different directory, you need can create a bash loop and tail each file separately.